# Google Maps JavaScript API v3 - How do I make getTilt() method return current tilt angle, not just value set by setTilt?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm working on a project using the Google Maps JavaScript API. When initializing the map, I added an if statement to add a css class if Google Maps cannot automatically show a tilted perspective. The map is initializing, but whether the map is tilted or not, `getTilt()` is returning 45.

Regarding `getTilt()` the API documentation says:

> **Return Value:  number**
> Returns the current angle of incidence of the map, in degrees from the viewport plane to the map plane. The result will be 0 for imagery taken directly overhead or 45 for 45° imagery. 45° imagery is only available for `SATELLITE` and `HYBRID` map types, within some locations, and at some zoom levels. Note: This method does not return the value set by `setTilt`. See `setTilt` for details.

I believe I'm following all of these rules, which leads me to believe the method *should* return the actual tilt angle. Here is my code:

```js
function initMap() {
  var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map');
  var mapOptions = {
    center: {lat: 39.7684, lng: -86.1581},
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
    zoom: 8,
    tilt: 45,
    draggable: false,
    scrollwheel: false,
    disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
    disableDefaultUI: true
  }

  var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, mapOptions);

  // Remove perspective if google maps can do it for us
  if (map.getTilt() !== 0) {
    mapDiv.className = "";
    map.setHeading(45);
  }

}
```

```css
/* # Reset
------------------------------------------------------------------------ */
*, *:after, *:before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box; }

html,
body,
ul,
ol {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0; }

body {
  color: #000;
  background: #FFF;
  font-family: "", sans-serif; }

/* # Map
------------------------------------------------------------------------ */
#mapHolder {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 75vh;
  position: relative; }

#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all 1s ease; }
  #map.hasPerspective {
    transform: rotateZ(-10deg) rotateY(30deg) rotateX(50deg) !important;
    position: absolute !important;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    top: -120%;
    bottom: -120%;
    left: -50%;
    right: -50%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    perspective: 100000px; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="mapHolder">
      <div id="map" class="hasPerspective"></div>
    </div>

    <!-- SCRIPTS -->
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap" async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong? I appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Google Maps Javascript API is event driven.  You shouldn't attempt to access the `tilt` property until it has been initialized.  The first time it is set the map `tilt_changed` event fires.  At that point it is set to 0.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'tilt_changed', function() {
  console.log(map.getTilt());
  // Add perspective if google maps can't do it for us
  if (map.getTilt() == 0) {
    mapDiv.className = "hasPerspective";
  } else { // Remove perspective when google maps can do it for us
    mapDiv.className = "";
    map.setHeading(45);
  }
  google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
});
```

**code snippet:**

```js
function initMap() {
  var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map');
  var mapOptions = {
    center: {
      lat: 39.7684,
      lng: -86.1581
    },
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
    zoom: 18,
    tilt: 45,
    /*    
        draggable: false,
        scrollwheel: false,
        disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
        disableDefaultUI: true
    */
  }

  var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, mapOptions);
  
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'tilt_changed', function() {
    console.log(map.getTilt());
    // Add perspective if google maps can't do it for us
    if (map.getTilt() == 0) {
      mapDiv.className = "hasPerspective";
    } else { // Remove perspective when google maps can do it for us
      mapDiv.className = "";
      map.setHeading(45);
    }
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
  });
}
```

```css
/* # Reset
------------------------------------------------------------------------ */

*,
*:after,
*:before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body,
ul,
ol {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  color: #000;
  background: #FFF;
  font-family: "", sans-serif;
}
/* # Map
------------------------------------------------------------------------ */

#mapHolder {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 75vh;
  position: relative;
}
#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
#map.hasPerspective {
  transform: rotateZ(-10deg) rotateY(30deg) rotateX(50deg) !important;
  position: absolute !important;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  top: -120%;
  bottom: -120%;
  left: -50%;
  right: -50%;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  perspective: 100000px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="mapHolder">
    <div id="map"></div>
  </div>

  <!-- SCRIPTS -->
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap" async defer></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick and helpful response! After implementing it, I realized that if the initial map was zoomed in enough that Google Maps could show tilt, the .hasPerspective class wasn't removed. To fix this, I just switched the if statement to default to no added perspective and only add the css class if needed. I suggested this edit in your answer. Thanks again!